# Sort rather than _id and apply pagination using last record id on that in mongod and nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, pagination

I'm applying **filtering **on my data using three different filters mentioned in my code.
this is my code

```
/* Initialize pipeline */
        const pipeline = [];

        /* All reviews of Auth Host */
        pipeline.push({
            $match: { host_id: new ObjectId(host_id) },
        });

        /* High rated on top */
        if (filter && filter == "Highest Rated") {
            pipeline.push({
                $sort: {
                    rating: -1,
                    _id: -1,
                },
            });
        } else if (filter && filter == "Newest") {
            /* Newest on top */
            pipeline.push({
                $sort: {
                    _id: -1,
                },
            });
        } else if (filter && filter == "Oldest") {
            pipeline.push({
                $sort: {
                    _id: 1,
                },
            });
        }
/* Pagination */
        if (last_rec_id) {
            let query;
            if (filter !== "Highest Rated") {
                query = filter === "Oldest" || !filter ? { $gt: new ObjectId(last_rec_id) } : { $lt: new ObjectId(last_rec_id) };

                pipeline.push({
                    $match: {
                        _id: query,
                    },
                });
            } else {
                query = {
                    $or: [
                        { rating: { $lte: 5 } },
                        {
                            rating: 5,
                            _id: { $lt: new ObjectId(last_rec_id) }, // Secondary sorting by _id
                        },
                    ],
                };
                pipeline.push({
                    $match: query,
                });
            }
        }
```

All filters are working well with pagination but the pagination using **last_rec_id **is not applying on **filter="Highest Rated"**, i'm getting records well but when i apply pagination it donot give accurate results,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Last Record Id I would prefer to paginate using Page Number.

```
/* Initialize pipeline */
const pipeline = [];

/* All reviews of Auth Host */
pipeline.push({
    $match: { host_id: new ObjectId(host_id) },
});

/* High rated on top */
if (filter && filter == "Highest Rated") {
    pipeline.push({
        $sort: {
            rating: -1,
            _id: -1,
        },
    });
} else if (filter && filter == "Newest") {
    /* Newest on top */
    pipeline.push({
        $sort: {
            _id: -1,
        },
    });
} else if (filter && filter == "Oldest") {
    pipeline.push({
        $sort: {
            _id: 1,
        },
    });
}

/* Pagination Logic */
if (page) {
    const pageSize = 10; // Change this to your desired page size
    const skipAmount = (page - 1) * pageSize;

    pipeline.push({
        $skip: skipAmount,
    });
}
```

Comment: Thankew Hassan for this solution, it really worked for me.

Comment: Glad to see that it helps you.